# Running into exec format issues with ARM64 script on 2020 macbook pro

Tags: macos, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am new to ARM64 so I probably made a simple mistake
I was trying to get a simple script to run but kept running into this error
(I am on a 2020 MacBook Pro with the latest Sonoma 14.0)
`zsh: exec format error: ./cubic`
I then tried to execute a simple helloworld script -

```
.global _start

.section .data
hello_message:
    .asciz "Hello, World!\\n"

.section .text
_start:
    mov x8, #64          
    mov x0, #1           
    ldr x1, =hello_message  
    ldr x2, =13           
    svc #0
    mov x8, #93          
    mov x0, #0           
    svc #0
```

I then compiled and linked it using -
`aarch64-elf-as -o hello.o hello.s`
`aarch64-elf-ld -o hello hello.o`

But I ran into the same issue for this script after running ./hello

```
zsh: exec format error: ./hello
```

After running file hello I get -

```
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

So I it should be executable right???
Is it how I compiled and linked it above that is causing this issue?

I have tried it in different terminals (warp vs console) and in different shells (bash vs zsh) and get the same error everyplace everytime

---

I tried executing an ARM64 executable with no (known) compiling or linking issues. The ideal output would simply be -
Hello, World!

Comment: You're trying to run a Linux binary on macOS.

Comment: Where did you get those tools?  Are you cross-compiling on a Linux system?  If you're ON an ARM Mac, you should just be able to use `as` and `ld`.

Comment: @TimRoberts , You are right. My professor is running it on Linux that's why I used those tools, Thanks!